# Rails with Devise giving 'No route matches [GET] "/post" ' message on Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using Devise for authentication. My routes.rb file has got those lines

```
devise_for :users
  unauthenticated :user do
    root to: 'home#index', as: :unauthenticated_root
  end
  authenticated :user do
    root to: 'search#index', as: :root
  end
```

On my landing page, after clicking on `Login`, rails gives me this error

```
Routing Error
No route matches [GET] "/post"
```

and rails routes gives me

```
    new_user_session GET         /users/sign_in(.:format)      devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST        /users/sign_in(.:format)      devise/sessions#create 
destroy_user_session DELETE      /users/sign_out(.:format)     devise/sessions#destroy
```

I really can't figure out why. Any help appreciated !!

Comment: Could you please add view code for `Login` link in the question?

Comment: Actually it comes from a form handled by a vue component.

Comment: From the details provided, it looks like from tag is not built properly. if you can share the vue component that would be good.